# Subtracting two array values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Here are the snapshots of the two arrays:

```
Array ( [assigned_todo_count] => 382 )
Array ( [delayedtasks] => 88 )
```

and I have used the `array_diff_asooc` function for subtraction of the arrays but I am not getting the result I expected.

```
foreach(array_diff_assoc($assigned_todo_count,$delayed_todo_count) as $item)
{
print_r($item);
}
```

The final result when doing `print_r` outputs `382`. I have to  find the difference between two arrays though final output results in the first arrays result.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to the structure of these arrays.  Are they separate, or are they 1 array that contains multiple values, or..?

Comment: 382 comes from the 1st array, so how should it be different?

Comment: i hve to substract 382-88= which result me 294

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is quite confusing.

Anyways, let me assumed that `Array ( [assigned_todo_count] => 382 )` is stored in `$atc` variable and `Array ( [delayedtasks] => 88 )` is stored in `$dt` variable.

So what I'll just have to do is:

```
$difference = $atc['assigned_todo_count'] - $dt['delayedtasks'] ;

if($difference > 15){
   //difference is greater than 15
}else{
   //difference is less than 15
}
```

Comment: suggest me where i was wrong by using array_diff method

Comment: array_diff doesn't literally subtract values. [Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) see what it really does.

Comment: and how could aply condition on if like  $difference = $atc['assigned_todo_count'] - $dt['delayedtasks'] > 15  is not working for some conditions.

Comment: Just what are you trying to achieve? Please be specific

Comment: i want like this two subtract and check conditions :      Assigned_Todos - delayedtasks_Todos > 15

Comment: So you want to check if **assigned_todos - delayedtaks_todos** is greater than **15**?

Comment: If so try : (Assigned_Todos - delayedtasks_Todos) > 15

Comment: yes sr i want like this  i was looking for condition i also know a-b would result me solution

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$array1 = array("assigned_todo_count"=>382);
$array2 = array("delayedtasks" => 88);
$subtracted = array_map(function ($x, $y) { return $y-$x; } , $array2, $array1);
$result     = array_combine(array_keys($array2), $subtracted);
var_dump($result);
```

It will subtract array1 from array2

Comment: it result me negetive  values  ["assigned_todo_count"]=> int(-294)

Comment: I have edited the code now. Just check now please

Comment: but please help i was using array diif method for subtractng so where i was wrong.

Comment: Follow this link :
http://in2.php.net/array_diff_assoc
Its well explained there.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use this simple method?

```
<?php
 $array1 = array("assigned_todo_count"=>382);
 $array2 = array("delayedtasks" => 88);
 $result=$array1['assigned_todo_count']-$array2['delayedtasks'];
 echo $result;
?>
```

**Output**

294